# Finding view of an icon in overflow menu

Tags: android, toolbar, menuitem

I am trying to findview of an overflow icon. After clicking and opening the overflow icon, I tried using in onoptionsitemselected:

```
View view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.menu_tag); // null
View view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainMenu); // not null.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/mainMenu"
    android:title="@string/text"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_vert_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_tag"
            android:icon="@drawable/tag_32"
            app:showAsAction="always|withText"
            android:title="@string/tags"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/user_32"
            app:showAsAction="always|withText"
            android:title="@string/profile"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_debug"
            android:icon="@drawable/insect_32"
            app:showAsAction="always|withText"
            android:title="@string/debug"/>
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

It is giving me null but working fine for actionbar items.

Comment: where is mainMenu inflated ?

Comment: It must be inflated internally by android since it is in overflow icon. But the overflow menu is open so it must be inflated.

Comment: I am adding the menu for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by setting actionview to imagebutton and then finding the view.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to find view in  `onCreateOptionsMenu` method like this :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.optionsMenu = menu;
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menufile, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.mainmenu);

return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need view to use with this library - https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/uk/co/deanwild/materialshowcaseviewsample/CustomExample.java. You can check the onoptionsitemselected in this library.

Comment: Unfortunately still null. I think it will work only for icons for which we set actionview.

Comment: yes view will return null but MenuItem will not return null you can perform operation on 'item'